# UICollectionView cells crowd with auto rotation

Tags: uiviewcontroller, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with the default Flow layout that scrolls horizontally. When I rotate the device, the cells overlap each other.

When I rotate back to the initial launch orientation, the layout fixes itself.

I have tried calling invalidateLayout and reloadData in the didRotate~ method, both had no affect.

Any ideas?

Cheers!